# Sending requests Google Kubernetes Engine, multiple deployments, under one external IP address

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, devops, nat

The Google Cloud Platform Kubernetes Engine based backend deployment I work on has between 4-60 nodes running at all times, spanning two different services.

I want to interface with an API that employs IP whitelisting however, which would mean that all outgoing requests would have to be funneled through one singular IP address.

How do I do this? The deployment uses an Nginx Ingress controller, which doesn't allow many options when it comes to the *egress* part of things.

I tried setting up a VM outside of the deployment, but still on GCP in the same region, and was unable to set up a forward proxy. At least, not one that I could connect to off my local device. Not sure if this was because of GCP's firewall or anything of that sort. This was using Squid, as well Apache, with no success in either.

I also looked at the Cloud NAT option, but it seems like I would have to recreate all the services, CI/CD pipelines, and DNS settings etc. I would ideally avoid that, as it would be a few days worth of work and would call for some downtime of the systems as well.

Ideally I would have a working forward proxy. I tried looking for Docker images that would function as one, but that does not seem to be a thing, sadly. SSHing into a VM to set up such a proxy hasn't led to success yet, either.

Comment: I think if you remove the external IP addresses from the nodes, you can send the requests through Cloud NAT. I would say all other options will add a point of failure. You still should be able to set a NAT VM. This is how to do it: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway

Answer (score 1):

You have already found the solution, you have to rebuild things using either Cloud NAT or an equivalent solution made yourself. Even that is relatively recent and I've not actually tried it myself, as recently as a 6 months ago we were told this was not supported for GKE. Our solution was the proxy idea you mentioned, an HTTP proxy running outside of GKE and directing things through it at the app code level rather than infrastructure. It was not fun.